# RPC Server is unavailable when trying to deploy pocket pc application

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2008, windows-10, compact-framework, rpc

I'm currently developing an application for pocket pc in vb.net (.net compact framework 3.5) using Visual Studio 2008. The first time I deploy the application after starting VS it goes smooth but after the first deployment I keep getting the error "RPC Server is Unavailable". The only way to deploy again afterwards is to restart visual studio which can get annoying since I have to make dozens of deployments everyday.

I check Windows services manager and the RPC Server is running fine.

Any ideas of what might be causing this issue? I upgraded recently to Windows 10, never had this problem before on Windows 7.

Comment: After some research and a few missed tries this was what solved it for me:http://www.junipersys.com/Juniper-Systems-Rugged-Handheld-Computers/support/Knowledge-Base/Support-Knowledge-Base-Topics/Desktop-Connection-ActiveSync-or-Windows-Mobile-Device-Center/WMDC-in-Windows-10

Answer (score 0):

clean solution from the parent project and rebuild worked for me.